# Pivotal Server 3.1 not Working in STS 3.6.4

Tags: java, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am new in Spring. I'm trying to run my application using Pivotal 3.1 server in STS 3.6.4 & the server is showing the following error:

**Error**: Could not find or load main class sw.sts.sts.sts-bundle.pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE.base-instance.conf.logging.properties
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

When I searched for the logging.properties file, it is present in base-instance/conf in my pivotal's server directory. I've JDK 8 set in Runtime environments.

Comment: Did you upgrade Eclipse to STS 3.6.4 or just downloaded STS 3.6.4 distro? I've just tried the 3.6.4 distro and it seems to work fine to me... Don't think I recall seeing such error either... If you are still experiencing this problem lets move the discussion over to STS JIRA. Please create a defect here https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS select SERVER as component. Attach the STS log file, your app log and possibly your app and we'll take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Happened due to space in the tc server runtime installation path.

Manually adjust the launch config for the tc server instance via Run -> Run Configurations... switch to Arguments tab. Find the value for -Djava.util.logging.config.file argument value and surround the value with double-quotes.

Problem is https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4198 Fixed for STS 3.7.1.